# Make IRDA hotkeys work in the lock screen

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon, remote-control

I have some IRDA reciever and remote controller. Some keys on it emulates hotkeys. So, I've created a hotkey that locks my current session. Now I want to create one that will unlock it (for example, using `xdotools`). But cinnamon's hotkeys don't working on lock screen. So, how can i make it work?